# Gunicorn error: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 Digital Ocean server for my Django website, with Nginx & Gunicorn. When I perform `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`, I get [image: this error] on my server:

And I can't pinpoint what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I currently have this issue.

Comment: Really can't remember sorry. maybe try `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` and debug those settings

Comment: Oh, I stopped the service and started it again and I haven't had that problem since. Thanks